# Writing A Story and Need help with intro

Tags: creative-writing

I'm writing a story and I would an idea for the intro to open up the story. The story is about two kids who find an old box in their grandparents' garage holding papers about a covered stairway in their basement. When they go down that staircase they find the back of the declaration of independence, which is really a treasure map.

As the news spreads, the whole world finds out about it and, in the end, the kids walk up to the president and put it on the table and say "This may not be true".

Comment: How old are the two kids? And I'm not following the last part. Do they find an alternate declaration of independence and that's why they go to the president, essentially to tell him that the first one isn't true?

Comment: Also, I'm just throwing this out, but I wanted to mention that the movie National Treasure essentially has the declaration having a treasure map on it. Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean with yours to set it apart?

Comment: I voted to close as this may be a farce or the OP should watch *National Treasure*. Also, the question is too broad and might do better with Worldbuilding site.

Comment: Start with the climax,use flash- back.

Comment: I agree, this is far too broad; I cast the final close vote. Please have a look at [this page](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) our site [tour] for more information but the gist is that questions here have to be more specific than on a writing forum. Also, we don't allow questions that are asking [what to write](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/397/26).

Comment: @StuW just as questions about *what to write* are off-topic here, questions about *what to build* are off-topic on Worldbuilding.  We can provide reality checks for specific (world, not story) ideas, but our main focus is Q&A, not critique or idea-generation, same as here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always start with characters. I create a few and write a lot of scenes where they interact with each other. This is exploratory writing that might not make it into the final drafts, but it helps you figure out who your characters are, what their motivations are, what they think of each other, etc.

For me, the plot emerges from the characters. I never begin with the plot.

Looks like you'll need to find yourself a good proofreader at some point, too.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry too much about 'where to begin'. Just pick a moment, a scene from the story in your head, choose a couple of your characters (why not the main ones?) and 'let them talk'.

For now there's not even a need for your characters to be conversing along the lines of dialogs that serve the story. Just let them talk about whatever. Have them for instance sit down for dinner and talk politics, their workday or school day, etc.

The way I see it, you and your characters need to get used to one another. And this is a good way to accomplish that. After a while you will find that some parts of your story will start to seep into this free-wheeling you have going. That is the moment that you 'start' to tell your story.

If at this point anything you wrote is of any use, then by all means use it, otherwise just write it off (pun intended). The main thing is you've started writing your real story.